# using filepond with react and want to validate or prevent same name upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filepond

For File multiple upload using `<FilePond>` I want to make sure there’s no duplicate file name, like if there’s two file having same name then it should be like file.pdf and another file should get file(1).pdf and so on. 
How can I do this?

```
 <FilePond
                                    ref={ref => this.pond = ref}
                                    allowMultiple={true}
                                    acceptedFileTypes= 'application/pdf'
                                    onaddfile={async (error, fileItem) => {
                                        let obj = {};
                                        obj.id = fileItem.id;
                                        obj.name = fileItem.file.name;
                                        //obj.filestring = await this.toBase64(fileItem.file);
                                        obj.file=fileItem.file;
                                        obj.fileinProgress = false;
                                        obj.date = this.state.date;
                                        obj.report_type = this.state.selectedButton;
                                        obj.fileItem = fileItem.fileType;
                                        obj.readyToUpload = true;
                                        obj.fileUploaded = false;
                                        if (fileItem.fileType === 'application/pdf') {
                                            this.setState({ ["files" + obj.id]: obj});
                                        } else {
                                            toast.error("You can only upload PDF file");
                                        }
                                    }} />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check your uploaded files recursivly as below.

```
checkUploadedFiles(name,n=1){
if(uploadedfiles.find(up=>up.name===name).length>0){
checkUploadedFiles(`${name}(n)`,n+1)
}
return name
}
 onaddfile={async (error, fileItem) => {
                                        let obj = {};
                                        obj.id = fileItem.id;
                                        obj.name = checkUploadedFiles(fileItem.file.name)
                                        obj.file=fileItem.file;
                                        obj.fileinProgress = false;
                                        obj.date = this.state.date;
                                        obj.report_type = this.state.selectedButton;
                                        obj.fileItem = fileItem.fileType;
                                        obj.readyToUpload = true;
                                        obj.fileUploaded = false;
                                        if (fileItem.fileType === 'application/pdf') {
                                            this.setState({ ["files" + obj.id]: obj});
                                        } else {
                                            toast.error("You can only upload PDF file");
                                        }
                                    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always specify the *server* attribute on FilePond, override the *process* function in there, and have pre-validation happen to optionally reject some files. Part of your pre-validation could include a check to see if the file already exists, either by comparing to a global list of all current attachments or using the instance's *getFiles* function.

I had a need to do some cleanup for my files and put them into a format that my API could accept, which meant storing them in an array of wrapper objects then adding that to a larger object that was sent over the wire. Since I already needed to do this step, it was natural just to have pre-validation of unique file name happen here using the global list of files:

What that roughly looks like in practice is:

```
    <FilePond
    allowMultiple
    maxFiles={10}
    maxParallelUploads={10}
    server={
             { process: (fieldName, file, metadata, load, error, progress, abort) => {
                    if (this.attachments.findIndex(a => a.name == file.name) > -1) {
                        error(new Error('More than one file with the same name cannot be attached'));
                    }
                    this.attachments.push(file);
                    load(file.name);
              }
              revert: (uniqueFileId, load, error) => {
                    try {
                        const i = this.attachments.findIndex(a => a.name === uniqueFileId);
                        if (i > -1) {
                            this.attachments.splice(i, 1);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        console.error('error reverting attachment: ' + e);
                        error(e);
                    }
              }
            }
    />
```

Note that in my *revert* override, I also remove the attachment from my global list

Documentation here: https://pqina.nl/filepond/docs/patterns/api/server/#advanced

Hope that helps!